# Get cookies from httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, cookies

I'm trying to get all cookies from a website using this code

```
        CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.foetex.dk/ugenstilbud/Pages/Zmags.aspx");
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

        var response = request.GetResponse();

        foreach (Cookie c in cookieJar.GetCookies(request.RequestUri))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cookie['" + c.Name + "']: " + c.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

The only thing i want is to display with console.writeline, but im not getting a single of them.

Comment: This sets the _request's_ cookie collection to an empty list, then tries to look up a cookie from that list, which will return nothing. If you want a cookie returned from the web site you are contacting with your request, you need to look up cookies in the _response_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following example uses the HttpCookie class and its properties to read a cookie with a specific name.

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
myCookie = Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"];

// Read the cookie information and display it.
if (myCookie != null)
   Response.Write("<p>"+ myCookie.Name + "<p>"+ myCookie.Value);
else
   Response.Write("not found");
```

Retrieve the values in the [HttpWebResponse.Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.httpwebresponse%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). In this example, the cookies are retrieved and saved to isolated storage:

```
private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
        request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isf =
        IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForSite())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile("CookieExCookies",
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(isfs))
            {
                foreach (Cookie cookieValue in response.Cookies)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Cookie: " + cookieValue.ToString());
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, what to do i pass in as parameter to the function to retrieve the cookies.

Comment: @DavidJunker You're Welcome! me too i'm going to sleep :) If my answer has solved your problem click Accept as solution button, doing it will help others know the solution.

Comment: This is still too abstract for me, i can't quite see how to retrieve and display the tokens i want.

Comment: I tried to get it to make sense, it dosen't, and i don't see how i can use it to retrive cookies from e.g. my link. This is not a clear answer for my question, so i can't mark it as solved.

Comment: Your answer has too much unrelated information includng Async read and Isolated storage which has nothing to do with reading cookies from response

Answer (score 17):

```
//Please use this,
HttpWebRequest request = null;
request = HttpWebRequest.Create(StringURL) as HttpWebRequest;                
HttpWebResponse TheRespone = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
String setCookieHeader = TheRespone.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved me from troubleshoot this using this *awful* method: `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie]`

Answer (score 2):

To get the list of cookies, you can use the below method;

```
private async Task<List<Cookie>> GetCookies(string url)
{
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    var uri = new Uri(url);
    using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer
    })
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            return cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```