# Ranorex: How to Catch Cookie Content?

Tags: cookies, browser, automated-tests, ranorex

Is there a way to catch cookie content with a Standard Ranorex function? I guess it's ofcourse possible with a custom C# module. But if there is a standard "ClearCookie" function maybe there is a similar one to read Cookie content? I didn't find such a function so far.

Thanks, Rainer

Comment: Can't really find it either browsing the documentation. I'd go with C# custom code for this. For this you could create a library in your project to use the method everywhere in your test.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built in function in Ranorex to get http cookies. clearCookie is just a parameter not a method or function, but there is already a stackoverflow post which describes how to get Http-Cookies in C#

[Get cookies from httpwebrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380189/get-cookies-from-httpwebrequest)

If you want to have a built-in function in Ranorex you can submit a feature request http://www.ranorex.com/uservoice.html

Comment: lol, the UserVoice page is no longer active on that site