# How can i get cookies in web request using c#?

Tags: c#, cookies

I'm new to c# language. I want to write this code to post data to web url:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"Identifier={"anyUsername"}&Password={"Password"}");
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://users.tclnet.ir/Authentication/LogOn");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            string responseContent = null;
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr99 = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        responseContent = sr99.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
```

but i want get cookies from that answer,how can i write code to achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get cookies from httpwebrequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380189/get-cookies-from-httpwebrequest)

Comment: @CMedina i cant understand that ,please write me code